# Is it possible to call PyObject_CallMethod only once for a PySequence_Fast loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a python module implemented using the "C" API for Python 3.7. I'm trying to speed up a `PySequence_Fast()` loop that calls a function using `PyObject_CallMethod()`. Since the objects are all the same python class, I was hoping to avoid the overhead of resolving the function name each time.  Is that possible?

Here's the (reduced) code fragment I'm trying to improve:

```
    PyObject *seq = PySequence_Fast(object_list,"not a sequence");
    int len = PySequence_Size(object_list);
    for ( int n = 0 ; n < len ; n++ )
    {
        PyObject *obj = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq,n);
        PyObject_CallMethod(obj,"my_function",NULL);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just do the exact same thing you'd do in Python, but through the C API.

In Python, you'd be transforming

```
for thing in stuff:
    thing.method()
```

to

```
method = ThingClass.method
for thing in stuff:
    method(thing)
```

So do an attribute lookup on the class of your objects to find the unbound method, with [`PyObject_GetAttrString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_GetAttrString), and call it with [`PyObject_CallObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallObject) or [`PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs) or whatever means of calling things you decide is most convenient.